# React fire event or fire method on set value with useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

For a variable defined in this way:

```
const [voivodeshipDict, setVoivodeshipDictValues] = useState<IDictionary[]>([] as IDictionary[]);
```

For each call 'setVoivodeshipDictValues' I want fire other code after the value is set. Hot to implement that?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: i think you can use useeffect hook with "voivodeshipDict" in the dependency array and put the code you want to run in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `useEffect()` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Do stuffs whenever voivodeshipDict is changed
}, [voivodeshipDict])
```